# Hbase counters with Apache NiFi

Tags: groovy, hbase, apache-nifi

My task is simple -  I want to increment column value in HBase (counter) using Apache NiFi.

I have an accountid as a rowkey and I want to incr/decr balance column based on a streaming value.  What would be the best way to do it with NiFi.

For example starting value of balance=100 for account A.  I get (A, -20) as an event.  What is the best out of the box processor to get this done (A balance = 80).  It seems like all of them will just replace the value. I am also open to changing my schema...

I tried writing groovy script but getting this error in nifi.  It is just a simple put wonder if my basic structure is wrong.

2017-03-10 06:38:54,067 ERROR [Timer-Driven Process Thread-6] o.a.nifi.processors.script.ExecuteScript ExecuteScript[id=b5a0e7b7-015a-1000-ab9c-0696c8297e8d] ExecuteScript[id=b5a0e7b7-015a-1000-ab9c-0696c8297e8d] failed to process due to java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration; rolling back session:

```
import org.apache.nifi.controller.ControllerService
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseConfiguration
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.TableName
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Connection
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionFactory
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Get
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Put
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Result
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ResultScanner
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Scan
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Table
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Bytes

def lookup = context.controllerServiceLookup
def HbaseServiceName =HBaseClient.value
def HBaseServiceId = lookup.getControllerServiceIdentifiers(ControllerService).find { 
    cs -> lookup.getControllerServiceName(cs) == HBaseServiceName
}
def conn = lookup.getControllerService(HBaseServiceId)?.getConnection()
try {
    flowFile = session.create()
    def table = conn.getTable(TableName.valueOf("crap"))
    myfile = flowFile.getAttribute("filename")
    def p = new Put(Bytes.toBytes("crap")); 
    p.add(Bytes.toBytes("crap"), Bytes.toBytes("cf1"),Bytes.toBytes("SomeValue"))
    table.put(p);
    session.transfer(flowFile, REL_SUCCESS)
} catch(e) {
    log.error('Scripting error', e)
    session.transfer(flowFile, REL_FAILURE)
}
conn?.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that `PutHBaseCell` and `PutHBaseJSON` put the flowfile contents into the respective HBase destinations. What you probably want to do is use `GetHBase` to retrieve the initial value, keep a running counter using *counters* (see [here](https://pierrevillard.com/2017/02/07/using-counters-in-apache-nifi/) for a tutorial), and then update the HBase cell with the correct value. You can also use the [`DistributedMapCache`](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi.distributed.cache.server.map.DistributedMapCacheServer/index.html) system to fetch/calculate/store values in shared memory space.

Comment: Agree.  The issue with GetHbase (get current value) and add streaming value and finally do PutHBase (to update)   - Is that it is 2 operations and data comes back to the client (NiFi).  I like increment paradigm as it is a lot faster and I don't really care to read current value (i just want to increment it).  Throughput is a big issue for me.  I am bouncing around idea of running phoenix server on each NiFi machine and call phoenix-jdbc client with counter increment from NiFi.

Comment: I don't have much HBase experience. Could you use an `ExecuteScript` processor to do that in Groovy by including the HBase libs in the relevant modules folder? Here's an [example](https://github.com/larsgeorge/hbase-book/blob/master/ch04/src/main/java/client/IncrementMultipleExample.java) of using the HBase `Increment` object -- you should be able to [reference the HBase controller service from the script](https://funnifi.blogspot.com/2016/04/sql-in-nifi-with-executescript.html) as well.

Comment: Thanks Andy this seems to meet my requirements (will try) except involves doing a bit more coding than we had hoped for :).  Will post the solutions after done.

Comment: In the next release of NiF there is a FetchHbaseRow processor which is what you would likely want to use since GetHBase does not allow incoming flow files. So you would use FetchHBaseRow which gives you a JSON representation of the row, EvaluateJsonPath to extract the value to an attribute, UpdateAttribute to apply the +/- on the value, ReplaceText to write the new value to the content of the flow file, and then PutHBaseCell to write it back to HBase.

Comment: @andrewshved I'd also recommend [opening a Jira](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI/?selectedTab=com.atlassian.jira.jira-projects-plugin:summary-panel) documenting your desired functionality. Can't promise it will get picked up, but if other community members feel it's a valuable feature, there could be an `IncrementHBaseCell` processor added, etc.